# Array Adapter Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I'm trying to input an array into a ListView. I've gotten it to work for a spin box with this code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, model.getLocationsArray());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I run the next block of code the program closes unexpectedly. Strangely if I remove `model.getLocationsArray()` it runs but the view won't update.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.available_locations_list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model.getLocationsArray());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please tell what will model.getloactionArray() return

Comment: Could you post the stack trace, so we know what exception is being thrown.

Comment: Are you sure you initialize the Adapter<String> and its not a typo anywhere in the code?

Comment: Try changing the name of second adapter..

Comment: Log:


02-23 01:30:35.519: E/AndroidRuntime(538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 01:30:35.519: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smokin3joeynies/com.example.smokin3joeynies.EditLocationsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 01:30:35.519: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-23 01:30:35.519: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)

Comment: Changing adapter didn't work, they are in separate objects anyway

Comment: Got it, bonehead move. Was using existing code & it was writing to a file. Would help if they required some java before you can sign up for this class, I'm so lost it's scary.

Answer (score 0):

model.getLocationsArray() instead this... you can use directly Arraylist object. If you have.Nullpointer Exc. because of from your EditText value cant be added to your ArrayList.